# error call to member function set_value is ambigious (in xcode using pugixml library)

Tags: c++, xcode, pugixml

i am using pugixml in visual c++ express 2010. this code works. however when i use it in xcode. it gives me an error that 'call to member function ''set_value'' is ambigious'. 
can any body help in solving it or why it is giving me error in xcode.

```
for (size_t k = 0; k < num; ++k) {

    for (size_t v = 0; v < height; ++v) {

        if(width==2){
            pugi::xml_node weightNode = weightsNode.append_child("Test_Output");
            weightNode.append_attribute("No").set_value(k);
            weightNode.append_attribute("index1").set_value(v);
            weightNode.append_attribute("index2").set_value(v);  //as 1x2 case first value position is (0x0)
            weightNode.append_attribute("value").set_value(networks[k][6][0].at<double>(v,v));
            weightNode.append_attribute("index1").set_value(v);
            weightNode.append_attribute("index2").set_value(v+1);
            weightNode.append_attribute("value").set_value(networks[k][6][0].at<double>(v,v+1));
        }else{
            for (size_t u = 0; u < width; ++u) {
                pugi::xml_node weightNode = weightsNode.append_child("Output");
                weightNode.append_attribute("No").set_value(k);
                weightNode.append_attribute("index1").set_value(v);
                weightNode.append_attribute("index2").set_value(u);
                weightNode.append_attribute("value").set_value(networks[k][6][0].at<double>(v,u));
                weightNode.append_attribute("index1").set_value(v);
                weightNode.append_attribute("index2").set_value(u);
                weightNode.append_attribute("value").set_value(networks[k][6][0].at<double>(v,u));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can any body pinpoint why it is giving error in xcode. however it works properly in visual c++.

thanks

Comment: Within Xcode, right-click on `set_value` and find it's declaration and post where it says.  If it comes up with a choice then that is the root cause of the issue (I suspect it's a macro that's been defined or a global function).

Comment: Sorry, I am new did not understand where it what says? In all the places where i use set_value e.g. weightNode.append_attribute("No").set_value(k);   it says call to member function 'set_value' is ambigious

Comment: if you are talking about the function, it is a member function of pugixml library which works perfect when i use it in microsoft visual c++ 2010 express, but the same code give me error in xcode in mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/apiref.html#xml_attribute), there are overloads of `set_value` for several types:

```
bool set_value(const char_t* rhs);
bool set_value(int rhs);
bool set_value(unsigned int rhs);
bool set_value(double rhs);
bool set_value(bool rhs);
```

but not for `size_t`, unless it happens to be an alias for `unsigned int`.

You'll need to either change the type of `k` and `v` to `unsigned int`, or cast when calling `set_value`. If you need support for very large values which aren't representable by `unsigned int`, then you'll need a better library.

Comment: THank you so much Mike Seymour... It removed some of the errors... now trying for the rest... Thanks alot

Comment: "a better library" is uncalled for.

Comment: @zeuxcg: It's called for if this library doesn't meet the OP's needs. I can't judge that though, and it's most likely good enough, hence the "if".

Comment: hi, once again, i am trying to set values in windows this time, but time it ask only for const char_t* rhs values. no others. I passed string, i passed int, in all cases it gives error and ask for only const char_t* values. how can i fix that?